# Apostrophe as part of a word with regexp in MATLAB

Tags: regex, matlab, apostrophe

I am working on something in MATLAB that processes text. For this I need my regular expression to work properly.

So far I have this regexp below, which works for almost everything, but I would like to add something to it so that it reads an apostrophe as a part of a word.

```
V1 = regexp(inpstr,'\w*[^a-zA-Z0-9\ _\ -\ "\ *\f\n\r\t\v\x20]?','match');
```

So, my an examplary question is: If I have a string:

`'Hi, let's play some ball.'`

I would like the regexp to give me `'Hi,' - 'let's' - 'play' - 'some' - 'ball.'`

and currently it gives me `'Hi,' - 'let' - 's' - 'play' - 'some' - 'ball.'`

I guess the problem is I can't just add \ ' to the regexp because of MATLABs use of '.
I tried just adding it and this happened: `??? Error: File: TestScript.m Line: 13 Column: 38
The input character is not valid in MATLAB statements or expressions.`

Any help would be greatly appreciated =)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding Apostrophe in a string - Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984804/adding-apostrophe-in-a-string-matlab)

Comment: I need it to work without manipulating the input text.

Comment: try to use \' ' instead of \' as u need to escape that..

Comment: What do you mean "without manipulating the input text"?

Comment: I thought the solution in the link was to add an extra apostrophe to the string. That would be a manipulation.

Comment: @Rinku That doesn't work either :/

Comment: @Rinku Woops, that does work. I must've made a mistake earlier... Anyway I found it on a link from mathworks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was this:

`V1 = regexp(inpstr,'\w*[\'']*[^\_\-\"\*\s]*','match')`

Basically, in between `[ ]` you put characters you want to express and in between `[^ ]` you put characters you want to skip. Also, `\s` was a shortcut for all whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
\w*[^a-zA-Z0-9\ _\ -\ '\ "\ *\f\n\r\t\v\x20]?
```

Comment: try to use \' ' instead of \'

Comment: I found out that MATLAB has the apostrophe ' as char(39) (ascii character)... Now I need to find a way to use char(39) in the regexp so that it works.

Comment: When I find out how to use the char(x) command in the regexp command i can do something like regexp(inpstr,'\w*char(39)*\w*','match'), but I guess matlab does not recognize ascii in a text? ... I could use the . for 'any character' ... I'll try it with that.